# How do you parse comments with HTML tags in Eclipse?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, comments

I am reading a codebase written some times ago, and the comments are embedded with HTML tags such as `<p>` and `<ul>`. For example:

```
/**
* Class Description
* <p>
* List of configurations
* </P>
**/
```

If I put my mouse over the function, it correctly shows the formatted comment, but if I am in the file, the comments are not formatted, and the tags are exposed. Is there a way to view these comments in HTML formatted way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is Java code.

These are JavaDoc comments (they start with `/**`). You can't see them formatted in the actual Java editor.

You can open the 'JavaDoc' view (use 'Window > Show View > Javadoc') which will show you the formatted JavaDoc for the currently selected item in the Java editor.

Comment: Yep, it was Java comment. Thanks